# Uso de using versus nome completo

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, estilo-de-codificação, namespace

Eu tenho acompanhado muitos projetos *open source* e percebi que há uma alternância bem grande entre usar `using` (`Imports` no VB.NET) e usar referência direta para o `namespace`.

Exemplo:

```
void Main()
{
    System.Int32 i = 10;
    System.Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

ou

```
using System;
void Main()
{
    Int32 i = 10;
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

A minha dúvida é: há alguma **convenção** de quando deve ser usado a *referência direta* ou `using`/`Imports`? Ou então, há alguma diferença significante entre esses dois usos?

Comment: Olha geralmente usamos a referencia inteira pois caso houve-se System.Console.WriteLine e Output.Console.WriteLine e usa-se using não se saberia qual Console usar.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Não há um critério claramente estabelecido. É mais gosto.

Algumas pessoas preferem sempre usar de uma forma ou da outra. Outras preferem alternar dependendo do que está sendo usado ou mais ainda de quantas vezes é usado. Se você vai usar um nome só uma vez, costuma ser mais fácil escrever ele inteiro no local de uso em vez de fazer uma "importação". Mas tem a desvantagem que tira a consistência.

A minha observação pessoal é que é raro o uso do nome completamente qualificado e há preferência pelo `using`/`import`. O uso do nome completo só é adotado, na maioria dos casos, quando existe um conflito de nomes.

Ainda assim é possível aplicar o `using` criando um alias próprio desta forma (crédito para o dcastro nos comentários):

```
using WF = System.Windows.Forms.
```

Aí você usa o alias criado (`WF`) para desambiguar os nomes.

O C# 6 incentiva a adoção do `using` um pouco mais já que agora até classes estáticas podem ser importadas, ou mesmo membros estáticos de classes normais.

Em outras linguagens isto pode ser diferente, mas parece que você se preocupou com C# e VB.NET secundariamente. Então pergunte-se quantas vezes você viu alguém usando a primeira forma.

Cada vez mais será comum usar:

```
using System;
using static System.Console; //C# 6

void Main() {
    int i = 10; //raramente se usa o tipo do .NET, prefere-se o alias da linguagem
    //ou usa-se o var mesmo, neste caso
    WriteLine(i); //C# 6
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Syntax/UsingStatic2.cs).

Comment: É, eu formulei a pergunta já pensando no `static using` do C# 6.0. Eu quis perguntar num geral mesmo, mas tenho uma preferência por **C#** e **VB.Net** por causa da minha experiência. Sobre usar `int` ou  `var` ao invés de `Int32` eu estou ciente só usei `Int32` para reforçar o exemplo. De qualquer maneira, muito obrigado.

Comment: Acrescentaria ainda que, caso hajam dois tipos com o mesmo nome *in scope*, e se pretenda usar apenas um, pode-se desambiguar com `using SomeClass = Fully.Qualified.Name.SomeClass`. Portanto, quase nunca é necessário referir-se ao tipo pelo seu nome completo.

Answer (score 4):

Não há nenhum padrão porém, geralmente, usamos a referência direta pois caso houvesse `System.Console.WriteLine` e `Output.Console.WriteLine` e usassemos `using / import` não se saberia qual Console usar gerando assim um conflito de nomes.

Comment: "usamos a referência direta pois **caso houvesse** (...)" - Porquê usar uma solucao para um problema que não existe? Ambiguações são extremamente raras, não faz sentido usar o nome completo com frequência. Fazer disso padrão apenas contribui para reduzir a legibilidade do código.

Comment: O problema ainda não existe, pode ser que em c# (tag que o AP adicionou depois de todas as respostas) não haja tanto mas já ocorreu comigo trabalhando com C++/OpenCV/Tesseract

Answer (score 3):

Não há nenhuma convenção.

Muitos usarão o `using`, só especificando o nome completo (com `namespace`) em caso de conflitos de nomes.

Com certeza não existe nenhuma regra, nem indicação.