# Posso remover todos os using que não estou usando?

Tags: c#, using

Peguei um projeto aqui ASP.NET C# e percebo que posso retirar vários "using".

Posso sair retirando estes `using` ou não?

Será que o `using` que não é usado na `class` pode ser usado por alguém que está usando a `class`? Não, né?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Pode sim. A diretiva `using` (não confundir com o comando `using` que é usado para liberar recursos) é só uma forma para evitar digitações e leituras muito grandes.

O Visual Studio indica bem o que pode ser retirado sem medo.

Todos os tipos possuem *namespaces*, ou seja, sobrenomes para eles. [Para usar só nome e não o sobrenome usamos o `using`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/75343/101), assim todos os tipos contidos no *namespace* fica disponível naquele código pelo seu nome a partir de onde o `using` for usado.

Se você não usa um nome daquele [*namespace*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11199/101) ele não é necessário. Não só não gera problemas, a retirada pode evitar problemas te deixando usar algo sem querer que está disponível porque deixou algo sem necessidade ali. Você usa achando que é uma coisa, mas é outra. Não é grave, provavelmente perceberá o erro logo, mas atrapalha.

Desde C# 6 é possível usar o [`using` para classes estáticas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135423/101) também.

Falei sobre o assunto em [Using não utilizados afetam a performance?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16563/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 16):

Com o botão direito to mouse (na janela do código), acesse a opção > **Organize Usings > Remove Unnecessary Using.**

Você não terá nenhum problema em seu código, pois, poderá adicioná-los novamente.

Alguns posts relacionados

- [How to remove unused using namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12075909/how-to-remove-unused-using-namespaces)
- [Why remove unused using directives in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/629667/why-remove-unused-using-directives-in-c)

[image: Remove Unnecessary Using]

Comment: Legal quando aprendemos algo super útil não é?! Valeu!

Answer (score 10):

Não há problema em remove-los (os que não estão sendo utilizados normalmente ficam com um tom menos destacado), uma boa alternativa para tornar menos trabalhosa esta e outras ações é a ferramenta gratuita [Productivity Power Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.ProductivityPowerTools)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Toda vez que salvar, a ferramenta remove automaticamente os `Unnecessary Using`

Answer (score -2):

O jeito mais simples no Visual Studio é apertar Ctrl + R e Ctrl + G.