# DataBindTable Incompatível com SqlDataReader não implementa IEnumerable

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net

Estou com um problema em mostrar os dados de uma coluna que esta no [sqlserver](/questions/tagged/sqlserver), para inserir como x e y no meu chart em [asp.net](/questions/tagged/asp.net).
O problema é o seguinte, pelo que parece o método (`DataBindTable`) está a espera de `IEnumerable` mas o meu `SqlDataReader` não implementa `IEnumerable`.
Se me conseguissem dar me exemplos de como ultrapassar esta dificuldade agradecia.

Aqui segue o código de inserção:

```
protected void Chart1_Load13(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CS"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT [Consumo_Medio_Real], [Tipo_de_Fatura]  FROM [dbo].[t_faturas]", con);
        con.Open();

        SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        Chart1.DataBindTable(rdr,"Consumo_Medio_Real");
    }
}
```

Este é o código da conexão:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="CS" connectionString="Data Source=ASUS;Initial Catalog=DB_SACC;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=1234" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Aqui estão os `usings`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms; 
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Data;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Threading;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting;
using System.Data.DataTable;
```

Answer (score 1):

Esta solução pode te ajudar:

```
var dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
dt.Load(rdr);

var enumerableTable = (dt as System.ComponentModel.IListSource).GetList();
Chart1.DataBindTable(enumerableTable, "Consumo_Medio_Real");
```

Comment: obrigado esta a dar este erro alguma ideia de como resolver ? Error 2 'DataTable' is an ambiguous reference between 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.DataTable' and 'System.Data.DataTable"

Comment: @DiogoGomes resposta atualizada. Causou ambiguidade pq em seus `using` já está utilizando uma referência que também implementa uma classe `DataTable`.

Comment: acabei de por os usings para dar uma vista de olhos obrigado tem sido incansável @ismael

Comment: O que você mesmo citou:  `using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`. Veja esta [pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/176974/posso-remover-todos-os-using-que-n%C3%A3o-estou-usando) para outras informações.

Comment: ou seja retiro o  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel? @ ismael

Comment: Execute os procedimentos da pergunta que te mandei e isso fará uma limpeza em todas as referências não utilizadas. Se remover manualmente, sem saber, poderá gerar erros em seu código. Você poderá usar da forma que coloquei na resposta, não tem problema: `var dt = new System.Data.DataTable();`

Comment: agradeço a sua coperação@ismael

Comment: obrigado pela sua ajuda esta resolvido, foi me bastante útil@ismael

Comment: @DiogoGomes Marque esta resposta como aceita se realmente solucionou o seu problema. No [tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) isto é bem explicado.